# Inheritance with parametrized class

Tags: c++, inheritance, syntax-error

I have a parametrized class Queue and a subclass ClientsQueue not parametrized that inherits from Queue. I think I have a syntax error:

*client.h*

```
#ifndef CLIENT_H_
#define CLIENT_H_

class Client {
  public:
    Client();
    ~Client();
};
#endif
```

*queue.h*

```
#ifndef QUEUE_H_
#define QUEUE_H_

template <class T> class Queue {
  public:
    Queue();
    ~Queue();
};
#endif
```

*clientsQueue.h*

```
#ifndef CLIENTSQUEUE_H_
#define CLIENTSQUEUE_H_
#include "queue.h"
#include "client.h"

class ClientsQueue: public Queue<Client> {
  public:
    ClientsQueue();
    ~ClientsQueue();
};
#endif
```

*clientsQueue.cpp*

```
#include "clientsQueue.h"

ClientsQueue::ClientsQueue() {

};
```

*bank.cpp*

```
#include "clientsQueue.cpp"
int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

So, when I try to compile and run the program, the compiler says:

```
clientsQueue.cpp:3:1: error: ‘ClientsQueue’ does not name a type
 ClientsQueue::ClientsQueue() {
 ^
```

I can't see the error. If I quit all the code from `clientsQueue.cpp`, it works.

How can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: And what is in main function? Isn't ClientsQueue in other namespace?

Comment: The main file only includes the file, look again

Comment: I think there is some missing code. Do you ever have a `#endif` in queue.h? What is in client.h?

Comment: Does it work if you create ClientsQueue in main?

Comment: Generally you shouldn't `#include` .cpp files. You need to include the header file, then change the compiling of your project to have multiple files.

Comment: No, it does not works. Client is an empty class, look again please.

Comment: #include "clientsQueue.h" in bank.cpp not #include "clientsQueue.cpp"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `#include "clientsQueue.h"` not `#include "clientsQueue.cpp"` in main file. When you include header you present a declarations to the compiler. You miss the declaration of the class `ClientsQueue` when you include just the source (cpp) file.